# What is the chance of getting the "Couldn't pair with [device_name] because of an incorrect pin or passkey" alert even with no device bonded?

Tags: kotlin, bluetooth

## Situation

- The phone is not connected to any Bluetooth device.
- The phone has been connected to our Bluetooth device.

## Codes

Executing the following codes when the app comes to the foreground.

```
performBond(device)
> device.bluetoothDevice?.createBond()
```

or

```
performReconnect(device)
it = RxBlwDeviceServices
> it.discoverServices()
> it.getCharacteristic(NOTIFICATION_CHARACTERISTIC)
```

## Issue

- The OS shows the alert says "Couldn't pair with [device_name] because of an incorrect pin or passkey" even though the phone is not connected to any device.
- But the [device_name] is filled with our own Bluetooth device which the phone has been connected to before.
- It is like the phone is trying to connect to the device.

## Wonder

- How is it possible? Is there a chance to get the alert if the RxBlw keeps the device info?

## Environment

- OS: Android 11
- Do not know how to reproduce